# Jfrog API for list docker tags

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-container-registry, docker-tag

Getting 302 for the JFrog REST api for listing docker tags.

**Documentation:**

- https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/list-docker-tags

**Usage**:

```
GET /api/docker/{repo-key}/v2/{image name}/tags/list?n=<n from the request>&last=<last tag value from previous response>
```

**My query:**

- **repo-key** - docker-local
- **My image name** is like -> /eric/com.jfrog/test-app

So myquery is:

- https://jfrog.test.com/api/docker/docker-local/v2/eric/com.jfrog/test-app/tags/list

**Response:**

```html
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body>
    <center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
    <hr><center>nginx/1.17.5</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try with `https://` and full URL in the `curl` command.

Answer (score 6):

Artifactory API is exposed under `/artifactory/api...` path. At least for my Pro and JCR versions configured with nginx subdomains.

Try following paths:

1. Using general artifactory url:

   ```
   curl -u user:pass https://jfrog.test.com/artifactory/api/docker/docker-local/v2/my-docker-image/tags/list?
   ```
2. If you're using subdomain and reverse proxies e.g. image is available at `docker-local.test.com/my-docker-image:latest` than following path should be correct as well:

   ```
   curl -u user:pass https://docker-local.test.com/artifactory/api/docker/docker-local/v2/my-docker-image/tags/list?
   ```

For both cases `/artifactory/api/docker` are always. `docker-local` is the name of the repo (local or virtual) and `my-docker-image` is the name of the image. Probably for your path you should replace `my-docker-image` with `eric/com.jfrog/test-app`.

Comment: what does last do in the filter? not able to find good doc or example for it. Are there any other filters available? to filter tags starting with some string?

Comment: Can we pull only latest modified tag ?

Comment: To use a token rather than Basic Auth: `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" ...`